# Why does Linux treat accept() as read() operation in certain cases?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, epoll

Suppose we have a socket server in C that is implemented using polling methods such as [`poll()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or [`epoll()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html). And suppose the later is used (the same goes for `poll()`).

In any of the existing such servers, including the example in the `epoll()` man page, the `accept()` is called on listener whenever `EPOLLIN` event occurs. And it works. Which means that `EPOLLIN` event is triggered when the server has a pending connection to accept. However, the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html) definition of the `EPOLLIN` event says:

> EPOLLIN
> The associated file is available for read(2) operations.

This implies that `EPOLLIN` is an event specifically for `read()` operations.

Why can it be used for `accept()`? I went through all the relevant man pages and nowhere it is specified that `accept()` is treated as `read()` inside polling mechanisms. Yet is does work like that.

Comment: There isn't a specific event for `accept()`, so `EPOLLIN` is arbitrarily used for this.

Comment: It corresponds to the way `select()` adds the FD to `readfds` when it's acceptable.

Comment: @Barmar i understand, but why doesn't the manual say a thing about it. In fact, the manual is wrong to mention only `read()` in the description of the event

Comment: `EPOLLIN` just means the socket is in a readable state. A listening socket is in a readable state when it has a pending connection to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation of [`accept(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html):

> In order to be notified of incoming connections on a socket, you
> can use `select(2)`, `poll(2)`, or `epoll(7)`.  A readable event will
> be delivered when a new connection is attempted and you may then
> call `accept()` to get a socket for that connection.
> Alternatively, you can set the socket to deliver `SIGIO` when
> activity occurs on a socket; see `socket(7)` for details.